# S3 API Error : Access Denied AWS RDS LOAD DATA from S3 to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am trying to load a **CSV file in S3 bucket to RDS** table in AWS Aurora MySql.

Setup:

1. IAM - Create a Role for RDS to access S3 - having AmazonS3FullAccess policy.
2. DB Cluster Parameter Group - Included the Role created above to *aurora_load_from_s3_role* and *aws_default_s3_role* and Restarted the RDS instance.
3. RDS Manage IAM roles - Added the IAM role created above in point-1.
4. Grant privileges - provided `GRANT LOAD FROM S3 ON *.* TO '[USERNAME]'@'[IPADDRESS]'`
5. Run the LOAD DATA query - `LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3://[bucketname]/[key]/[filename].csv'
    INTO TABLE schemaname.tablename`

I am encountering **S3 API Error : Access Denied** : Access Denied.

Any suggestions to overcome this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe roles are wrong. You would have to provide them here. Is there any policy on the bucket?

Comment: Thanks for checking. No, there are no bucket policy or restrictions. I am able to send the data from RDS to S3 when i use LOAD DATA INTO S3. But not the other way around.

Comment: Don't know. Its just guessing game now. Are you owner of the csv object you are trying to read? Maybe its owned by some other account?

Comment: Yes, i am the owner of the document and also the bucket from which it is trying to get the csv within the same AWS Account. Very strange that it is working only one way.

Comment: Sometimes `Access Denied` actually means "File not Found", but it doesn't want to directly say that because it lowers security (by admitting that such a file exists). Can you double-check the naming of the CSV file? Check for case-sensitivity. You could grab the `s3://...` line and try it in the AWS CLI, such as `aws s3 ls s3://[bucketname]/[key]/[filename].csv` just to make sure the name is correct.

Comment: Yes, i am able to access using AWS CLI 2020-02-25 14:33:33      13942 XXXXXXXXTestExport_2020-02-25T09-03-30Z_part0.csv